# Excel 2010 - Auto populating a sheet based on data from another sheet in the workbook

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Thanks for taking the time to view my question!

I'm pretty new to Excel, trying to teach myself the basics to get stuff done at work. I've been asked to create a tracking spreadsheet for the maintenance and work orders performed on our fleet vehicles.

I would like to automatically populate a form I created on one sheet based on data from another sheet within the same workbook.

[FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caTds.png)

I would like to be able to enter the work order number in this space and have the form automatically filled out based on:

[TRACKER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J0zc.png)

I need the work order number, the equipment number, the date and the description to be populated within my form based on the data from my tracker.

I know it's possible as there is another tracker within our database that does the same thing, but it's not accessible by my department and the person that wrote it is no longer working here.

Comment: This is totally doable in Excel, but it's the perfect situation for using Access.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm currently using Access as an inventory (CMMS) control program but it was built by another coworker that isn't here any longer.

How hard would that be to set up?

Comment: If you aren't doing any calculations on the data, you could move the data in your TRACKER to an Access database, and then design a simple Access frontend that can act as your FORM. Since Access can uniquely serialise data entries, it will prevent accidental double ups of your Work Order numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily achievable with a couple very simple `VLOOKUP` formulas.

Here's an example spreadsheet showing the formula you would use in each field:
[image: Example Sheet with Formulas showing]

Here's the same spreadsheet showing how the results would work:
[image: Example Sheet showing filled in details]

To make this as simple as possible, I have referenced the table by name (`Table1`). This means that no matter where you move the formula, you're not going to accidentally break the link (unless you move it to another Workbook entirely).

To move the Report form to another sheet in the same workbook, you can actually just select the whole form, cut it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), then paste it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) onto the desired sheet.

---

To Reference a Table by name, you can start typing the name (in this case `Table`) into any formula and it will appear as an autocomplete option:

[image: Auto-completing a table name in a Formula]

Comment: Thank you Michael! That was ridiculously easy. I tried to copy the formula that the other tracker that I found and they did it a completely different way that looked quite confusing. This made perfect sense.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: @JolieG When you start pulling data from other Excel documents is when the trickiness starts to creep in.